I can't create new resolution on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to add a new resolution to my machine, which I have hooked up to the TV. I want 2K (1440p) output so I can use it to stream my games from my main PC so I don't have to move it. I am running a Nvidia GTX 550 Ti (I know ancient card but I had it lying around) and have the Nvidia 390 driver installed. I am using the dual-link DVI port which according to Nvidia should support 1440p:

Dual-link DVI Support: Able to drive industry’s largest and highest
resolution flat-panel displays up to 2560x1600 and with support
for High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP)

However everytime I use xrandr to set up the resolution using these commands:
cvt 2560 1440 60
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "2560x1440_60.00"

I get this error:
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30

I have already tried changing the HorizSync and VertRefresh in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf to the values my TV gives by parsing the edid information, however that did not work either. I have also tried getting the modeline from the edid information but did not work either. I have also tried running "cvt 2560 1440 60 -r" but no luck there either.
Is there anything else I could try?

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you follow the instructions here? Also, please be specific in your question when referencing the command you used like xrandr --addmode "2304x1440" instead of just xrandr --addmode, Thanks.

@mchid, yes I have followed those steps, I've updated my question to be more specific

If the cvt command gave you an output like # 2304x1440 59.81 Hz then try the command again with a lower refresh rate like cvt 2304 1440 59.80 as described here.

Otherwise, set Option "UseEDID" "FALSE" under Section "Device" in one of your /etc/X11/xorg.conf or other conf files in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d See here, here, and here.

Also, see the following answers.
